# SQL select rows that have duplicate data in other tables

Tags: sql, duplicates, db2

I have three tables

```
ID
TYPE
NAME
```

Example rows for Tables

ID Table

```
ID
-----
01
02
03
```

TYPE Table

```
ID | TYPE
---------
01 | CAT
02 | DOG
03 | CAT
```

NAME table (two different examples)

```
ID | NAME      ID | NAME
---------      ---------
01 | MIFF  or  01 | MIFF
02 | RUFF      02 | RUFF
03 | IFF       03 |
```

I am trying find the IDs that have same type but the name is different or missing.

The SQL query should return:

```
Duplicate1_ID | Duplicate2_ID
-----------------------------
01              03
```

since 01 and 03 are both CAT but 03 has a different name or its name is missing.
Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I understand this correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(n.name) over (partition by t.type) as min_name,
             max(n.name) over (partition by t.type) as max_name,
             sum(case when n.name is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by t.type) as num_nulls
      from type t join
           name n
           on t.id = n.id
    ) tn
where min_name <> max_name or num_nulls > 0;
```

That said, it seems like your data model is off.  You should have a table with one row per type.  That should have the one valid name associated with the type.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I corrected my expected SQL result.  I need 01 and 03 returned on the same row

Comment: yeah, the data model is too much.  this was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
select min(i.id) as duplicated1, max(i.id) as duplicated2 from idtable i inner join typetable t on i.id=t.id
where type=
(select typeval 
from types inner join name on types.id=name.id
group by typeval
having count(distinct types.id)>1 and count(distinct coalesce(nameval,'xxx'))>1
)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I corrected my expected SQL result.  I need 01 and 03 returned on the same row.  not sure if that makes things harder or easier...

Comment: @AlisonAftra, I've updated my answer - you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH 
  TYPE (ID, TYPE) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('01', 'CAT')
, ('02', 'DOG')
, ('03', 'CAT')
)
, NAME (ID, NAME) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('01', 'MIFF')
, ('02', 'RUFF')
--, ('03', 'IFF') 
, ('03', '')
)
*/
SELECT T1.ID ID1, T2.ID ID2
FROM TYPE T1
JOIN TYPE T2 ON T2.TYPE = T1.TYPE AND T2.ID > T1.ID
JOIN NAME N1 ON N1.ID = T1.ID
JOIN NAME N2 ON N2.ID = T2.ID
WHERE N1.NAME <> N2.NAME;
```